# kpartx or losetup?

Tags: linux, partition

If I have an image file or a data storage device that has no partition table but either has partitions or needs to be mapped to device nodes, which tool is better? A use case might be with flash devices that Linux creates partitions for at runtime from the `mtdparts` boot parameter.

Answer (score 1):

"*Has no partition table but either has partitions...*" makes no sense.  You can't have partitions on a device or image file without **some** kind of partition table.  I'm going to assume you mean "*has no partitions currently known by the kernel*".

Use `kpartx`.  It will use `losetup` if and when required (e.g. when you give it an image file rather than a device).